# Flutter firebase_messaging and firebase_auth

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification

After adding `firebase_auth: 0.18.1` to my project, push notification (onMessage) stop working on real iOS devices, but when app is minimized i receive pushes. On Android everything work properly.

I using this library to handle push `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.2`.

Development environment:

- Flutter 1.22.6
- Dart 2.20.5

My code to deal with push looks like that:

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          showNotificationDialog(message);
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: FirebaseController.backgroundMessageHandler,
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          showNotificationDialog(message);
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          showNotificationDialog(message);
        },
      );
```

On first run I ask for permissions

```
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((settings) {
      print("Settings registered:$settings");
    });
```

Right now i tried switch library version for messaging and auth, but this not help me.
I can not increase flutter or dart version because other libraries used in my app.
Do you have any suggestion what cause problem with receiving notifications?